# jquery toggle disappear quickly after clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, toggle

this is my code..

```
<div id="hint-toggle" class="ui-body ui-body-e" style="display: none">
   <p>No Hints available right now,check it later</p>
</div>

<button id="show-hint" onclick="showHint();"type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="c">Show Hint</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHint(event){
    $("#hint-toggle").toggle();
        }
</script>
```

After clicking `show hint` button it appear but within 2 sec it'll disappear.. did i miss anything in my code?? please help me.i want to show `hint-toggle` till i again press `show hint` button.

FYI: http://jsfiddle.net/shreeramns/rUKbh/

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NFena/1/

Comment: Seems fine to me too -> http://jsfiddle.net/JxbGJ/

Comment: make sure you are not clicking the button twice...code looks fine to me.. **check your mouse**.. :) :)

Comment: Is the submit button possibly refreshing the page?

Comment: @tymeJV yes my submit button refreshing the page.. 
<button type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Submit</button>

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the submit button from taking its default action, you should prevent the default action:

```
<button id="show-hint" onclick="showHint(event);" type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="c">Show Hint</button>
```

Notice how we pass in the `event` object in the JS

```
function showHint(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#hint-toggle").toggle();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DDsZn/

Comment: i tried this.. but `show hint` button still in active state. not return it's original state.

Comment: see this , after using event.preventDefault() show hint button goes active state.
 see this : http://jsfiddle.net/shreeramns/rUKbh/1/

Comment: did you see that? `show hint` button still in active, not returning it's original state.. @tymeJV